# Lambda function run without errors but nothing happen

Tags: python, file-upload, lambda, slack, slack-api

I've write a lambda function that download a file from a url and then upload this file to slack looks like bellow:

`job.py`

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
import urllib.request
import time


def execute():
    params = {'token': 'my-slack-token',
              'channels': 'test-channel', 'initial_comment': 'test-comment'}

    date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

    file_name = "/tmp/" + "file_name" + date + ".xlsx"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(
        'http://download-url', file_name)
    file = {'file': open(file_name, 'rb')}
    requests.post(url="https://slack.com/api/files.upload", params=params, files=file)
```

and `main.py`

```
import job


def execute(event, context):
    job.execute()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': "Done!"
    }
```

When cloudwatch trigger this lambda, the function run fine without errors but nothing happen. The file from url still not uploaded to slack.
What went wrong?
When I try this in local pc, file is uploaded to slack fine, but when in lambda, it's nothing happen.

Updated:
When I check logs in CloudWatch, it's look likes below:

```
START RequestId: a5ff4b71-4762-4c2a-badd-5be9f8ece494 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: a5ff4b71-4762-4c2a-badd-5be9f8ece494
REPORT RequestId: a5ff4b71-4762-4c2a-badd-5be9f8ece494  Duration: 568.63 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB  Init Duration: 142.49 ms    
XRAY TraceId: 1-5d77648c-5a6bf1079e4e6533b58ecd84   SegmentId: 3114b6ac2c50c17d Sampled: false
```

Comment: What does your lambda setting look like ? Have you checked the CloudWatch logs yet ? Probably a good place to start.

Comment: 1. you want to check for network issues, which you would find in the response object you get from `requests.post(...`
2. You want to check for API errors, which you find in the content of the response object. e.g. by running `api_response = response.json()`